# "still-warm" or "still-beating" heart - hyphen or no?

Tags: hyphenation, compounds

A copy editor wants to remove the hyphen from the "still-warm" in a (medieval-themed) comic:
*A noise very much like the sound of me ripping your still-warm heart from your ribcage.*

I understand there is a lot of variance in hyphen use, but my thinking is that the heart is that "still-warm" needs a hyphen to act as a single modifier. Am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I agree.  Maybe he thinks it's a still (not moving) warm heart.

Comment: Don't die on this hill. Let 'em have no hyphen. Die on other hills. You said it is a comic strip. In English and all over the globe, bosses like to be right.

Answer (score 1):

### I'd use the hyphen

**But I wouldn't cry if it was edited out.**

This use of the [hyphen](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/when-do-you-use-a-hyphen-in-english#:%7E:text=A%20hyphen%20is%20used%20to,before%20the%20noun%20it%20describes.&text=The%20hyphen%20is%20omitted%20when,He%27s%20six%20years%20old.) is to form a single adjective from multiple words. The advantage it has is that eliminates the potential confusion that the words might be two adjectives. For example, "still warm heart" could be read as either "still-warm heart" or "still, warm heart". Not so much a problem with "still beating" because a "still, beating heart" is a bit oxymoronic except, perhaps, in romance literature.

Of course, if you put the adjective after the noun, you don't use a hyphen and I quite like * A noise very much like the sound of me ripping your heart still warm from your ribcage.*